# SRAM AXS XPLR compatability 1x10

Tags: derailleur

I am considering buying an XPLR derailleur (and AXS shifters) for my gravel bike.

SRAM states the XPLR system is designed for a 1x12 drivetrain.

Would it also work with a 1x10 setup? Or even 1x11

Is it possible to change the number of rear gears that it will shift through via the AXS app?

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 4):

The XPLR uses the flattop chain, that is not compatible with other 12-speed chain (from SRAM and Shimano) - larger roller sizes, inside width. I doubt that the app will allow you to change the number of speeds: SRAM explicitly states that their EXPLR is 12-speed only (and 1x), so it's unlikely that they allow to change the number of speeds in the app.

Without entering in the consideration of the freehub body, and drivetrain in general, if your bike has currently Shimano, you will also need to replace the calipers. Shimano is using mineral oil, SRAM DOT fluid, that are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it *could* be possible to enable backwards or forwards compatibility through the app, keeping in mind any physical limits of the derailleur. For instance, if we re-designed bikes with longer freehubs for 15 speeds, a 12s derailleur likely wouldn't have the amount of travel. Anyway, [Archer Components](https://archercomponents.com) has an MTB system. The firmware in whatever is the brain of the system would need to support this.

None of the big 3 drivetrain companies allow you to select the number of speeds in their app. Maybe a very enterprising person could modify the firmware, but I've not heard of this being done. They have no economic incentive to do this, since they could cannibalize sales of new components, they would have to put active effort into developing firmware and software, and they would have to develop backwards compatibility tables. As time goes by, the complexity of the software would increase, thus increasing the chance of bugs. Bugs are annoying in Zwift and other online games. I have a feeling that cyclists would be extremely intolerant of bugs developing in our shifting systems.